# open graph tags - type=location. Not verifiying

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I've got a set of og meta tags in my page. When I go to the Facebook debugger and give it the URL it reports:

```
Meta Tag <meta property="og:type" content="landmark" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:latitude" content="51.5410881042" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:longitude" content="-0.145712554455" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:locality" content="London" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:region" content="Greater London" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:postal-code" content="NW1 7HY" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:country-name" content="United Kingdom" />
```

But returns an object property of :

og:type website

and then complains:

```
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:latitude'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:longitude'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:locality'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:region'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:postal-code'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:country-name'.
```

If I put in a og:type which is silly, like "beercan" it reports it as an invalid og type. So Landmark is recognised as a valid type but then ignored (and assumed to be website).

Anyone got any idea what is going on.

Comment: It looks like facebook have depreciated og:type  landmark. Can anyone confirm if this is true? The Facebook documentation is pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the rdf for the open graph protocol (at http://ogp.me/ns )and all those tags you mentioned above indeed have the comment starting with [DEPRECIATED]. It seems like all the tags that were originally included and were also defined in other ontologies are now depreciated. E.g. latitude was also defined in http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat. 
I run into this problem when trying to find the 'og:upc' object, which is now also depreciated.